# Learning to use open source software

Tags: oop, open-source

Do you know any book, blog, tutorial which explains in a detailed way the use of some open source projects? Maybe you have written such a tutorial, example of open source libraries, and your final product is great for a beginner to understand it.

I'm in the learning stage of OOP and I really need to learn by examples. I'll like to find some text which explains the use of some open source software/libraries and the good practices. Beign honestly I feel scared to use the open source libraries as I wish/think at this moment. I feel like as I still write procedural code and not OOP.

Do you know such tutorials, links, blogs, stories, pages?

PS: I know C and PHP. I can't say that I know C++ yet, and that's why I need your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with [one of the most popular Stack Overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books).

Then head over to the [FLOSS Manuals](http://en.flossmanuals.net/) site for manuals about all sorts of open-source tools.

If you still have questions, use the Stack Overflow search box liberally!

Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

Many open source projects have their own documentation pages. So if you are willing to use a library or a project you can refer to the documentation.
Or else you want to get involved in any open source projects.

Read these things,

- http://www.kegel.com/academy/opensource.html
- http://jakarta.apache.org/site/understandingopensource.html